# Oracle: convert java date to Oracle date in java program

Tags: java, oracle

I have a java program that reads the date as string from an input file and updates the Oracle table, where this date is part of an index fields.

I tried the following options:

a) Reading the data from csv file delimited by ; as String

```
109920541;2013-01-17 11:48:09;EDWARD ANTHONY;
```

b) Using SimpleDateFormat convert String to Date in a routine:

```
  java.text.SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  java.util.Date dt = formatter.parse("2013-01-17 11:48:09");
```

c) Use this date to prepare my sql stmt:

```
String update_query = "UPDATE "+ tableName +" SET NAME = ? WHERE ID = ? AND DATE_TIME = ?";
java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPwd);  
java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(update_query);
if (dt not null) {
  pstmt.setObject(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(dt.getTime()),java.sql.Types.DATE);
}
pstmt.executeBatch();
```

d) This does not find the date which is a part of key and so the data is not updated.

In sql developer I use the below query to fetch row:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ID = '1099205410'
AND DATE_TIME = TO_DATE('2013-01-17 11:48:09', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

How to convert a java String to Oracle date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single line:

```
pstmt.setString(1, name);
pstmt.setInt(2 id);
pstmt.setTimeStamp(3, ew java.sql.Timestamp(dt.getTime()));
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

If the DATE_TIME value is not always present in the CSV data, simply use a second PreparedStatement; with just 2 parameters.

If you are using a loop reading the lines, do

```
for ... {
    ...
    pstmt.clearParameters();
    pstmt.setString(1, name);
    pstmt.setInt(2 id);
    pstmt.setTimeStamp(3, new java.sql.Timestamp(dt.getTime()));
    pstmt.addBatch();
}
pstmt.executeBatch();
```

You might consider using the new time APIs.

(UPDATE is for *existing* records.)